# some error failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.11.4`

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I tried to create my first substrate chain. [Create Your First Substrate Chain](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup)

But I got some error while compiling substrate.

**failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.11.4`**

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you on Apple M1? If, so there are currently issues with building rocksdb there. See here an approach: https://vikiival.medium.com/run-substrate-on-apple-m1-a2699743fae8

Comment: This needs more clarity. What are your dependencies, platform, and more specifically *what is the full output of the build error*?

Answer (score 22):

You need to install additional library:

`sudo apt install clang` should help.

Comment: I have old mac and brew require os version 10.16 while I have 10.14
any solutions for me please

Comment: The solution works for Linux based OS, I do not know issues with old mac so not able to help.

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install make clang pkg-config libssl-dev
```

This should do the trick.
Reference: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/65

Comment: Thanks ! That did the trick for a project I'm working on, in the Solana ecosystem !

Answer (score 1):

From [@apopiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6597519/apopiak)

> Are you on Apple M1? If, so there are currently issues with building rocksdb there. See here an approach: vikiival.medium.com/run-substrate-on-apple-m1-a2699743fae8

Also others have reported needing to:

> You need clone the rust-rocksdb repo and checkout the commit listed here: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/122 then you can create a config.toml file in your .cargo folder in your home directory and add a path to that cloned repo

Answer (score 1):

You had better update cargo to the nightly version and then try it.
If it keep in stuck error try comment commands, you may will need to study link.

#rustup component add --toolchain=nightly rust-src rustfmt

```
rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

#apt-get install llvm clang linux-headers-"$(uname -r)" #

```
apt install llvm clang
cargo build --release
```

#cargo fix --allow-dirty #cargo fix --edition

```
 #lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
   Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
   Release: 20.04
   Codename:    focal
 #ldconfig --version
   ldconfig (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
 #cargo --version
   cargo 1.60.0-nightly (25fcb13 2022-02-01)
 #rustc --version
   rustc 1.60.0-nightly (f624427f8 2022-02-06)
 #rustup show
   Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
   rustup home:  /root/.rustup
   installed targets for active toolchain
 --------------------------------------
 wasm32-unknown-unknown
 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
 active toolchain
 ----------------
 nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
 rustc 1.60.0-nightly (f624427f8 2022-02-06)
```

> #ArmanRiazi.blockchain#Substrate#Dr.GavinWood
> For details:
> [Walk-Through/Substrate/NodeSetup](https://read.cash/@arman-riazi-science/walk-throughsubstratenodesetup-99fab8a8)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the to this version: "6.20.3"
checksum = "c309a9d2470844aceb9a4a098cf5286154d20596868b75a6b36357d2bb9ca25d"

am running on M1!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works for me as well, running on macOS. Just updated Cargo.lock file and everything started working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For me, on intel (x86_64-apple-darwin) MacOS, fix was in uninstalling brew installed llvm.

```bash
brew uninstall llvm
```

and using one installed from Apple's Command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

So for me what works was:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++
```

I tried several things but, after downloading g++ on Ubuntu running WSL2 worked for me and I was able to build and run frontier and run with the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/
cd frontier
cargo build --release
./target/debug/frontier-template-node --dev
```

And to see the blockchain explorer I used this link `https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#?rpc=ws://127.0.0.1:9944`